# Почему не считается последнее число?

Tags: python

Это мой код:

```
number1 = int(input("Укажи начало интервала:"))
number2 = int(input("Укажи конец интервала:"))
if number1 and number2 < 0:
    print("Введи пожалуйста позитивное число")

while number2 <= number1 :
    print("Концу интервала нужно быть больше чем начала интервала!")
    break

for i in range(number1, number2 + 1):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        
        c = sum(i for i in range(number1, number2) if i % 4 == 0)
print("В интервале чисел от "+str(number1)+"до "+str(number2)+",сумма чисел, которая делится на 4 : "+str(c))
```

Задача этой программы высчитывать сумму чисел, которые делятся на 4 в интервале чисел , которые я могу указать. Проблема в том, что например при введении чисел 3 и 32, он показывает сумму 112, а правильный ответ 144(сами можете посчитать), следовательно он не считает последнюю цифру 32, так как 112+32=144. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: если ответ вам помог то пожалуйста примите его

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(number1, number2 + 1):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        
        c = sum(i for i in range(number1, number2) if i % 4 == 0)
```

Зачем здесь первый цикл `for`, от него можно просто избавиться.

в `range(number1, number2)` к `number2` надо прибавить `1`

```
c = sum(i for i in range(number1, number2 + 1) if i % 4 == 0)
```

---

Не правильная проверка:

```
if number1 and number2 < 0:
```

должно быть:

```
if number1 < 0 or number2 < 0:
```

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо